# How to build c program for multiple platform?

Tags: linux, gcc, ipmitool

I followed this page(https://github.com/ipmitool/ipmitool/blob/master/INSTALL) and run "./confirgue --build=x86_64" to built ipmitool.c on CentOS7.9. But the built file run on ubuntu20.04 will show "./ipmitool: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory."

Q: Is it probable to build a portable ipmitool for multiple Linux platforms?

Comment: Error said you not have this shared lib `libreadline.so.6`, so you should to download this lib. It's nothing with `portable`.

Comment: @hstk, thanks for your reply. I try to use the command ln -s can solve library problems that cannot open shared objects. But one library, libcrypto.so.10, after creating the symbolic link and running the file, I will get version "libcrypto.so.10" not found. This library seems only for CentOS, so, I cannot run the file on ubuntu? Or have other methods can solve it?